# HttpClient - UrlEncodedFormEntity xml encode NameValuePair

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

xml is not encoding proper - any help

```
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VENDOR", "pradeep"));            
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("REQTYPE", "ExternalSystem"));
            formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DATA", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
```

my out is `VENDOR=pradeep&REQTYPE=ExternalSystem&DATA=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E`

but i expected this out

```
VENDOR=D-B165&REQTYPE=EXRCTRFREQ&DATA=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
```

any one how to do above

Thanks, Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the output from your UrlEncodedFormEntity() call is correct - it has URL encoded all of the NameValuePairs in formparms ala [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

You don't mention the use case for your expected output, but this will do what you want by simply concatenating the NameValuePairs w/o the encoding:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<NameValuePair> i = formparams.iterator();
while( i.hasNext() )
{
    sb.append( i.next().toString() );
    if( i.hasNext() )
        sb.append( "&" );
}
```

and if you still need an HttpEntity that honors that output you could try using StringEntity with something like:

```
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity( sb.toString() );
```